# Automatically Move Auxiliary Files to Subdir with Auto-Compiling Vimtex

Tags: pdftex, auxiliary-files, latexmk, vim, evince

I've seen numerous ways to move auxiliary files to a given directory via latexmk, or pdflatex (ex. `latexmk -auxdir=/tmp <file>`). But I am using **vimtex** with auto-compiling, so that whenever I save my tex file, it is automatically compiled and my pdf viewer (just using `evince`) is updated too.

What I'd like is for **vimtex** to create a subdir called `aux` in whichever directory my current texfile is, and put any of these auxiliary files in there at each compilation -- keeping just my `.tex` and `.pdf` file in the working dir. I feel like I should be able to specify this in `.latexmkrc` but haven't read any mention of specifying such settings there.

Comment: There is a [tag:vim] tag.  I've added it.

Comment: Note that `/aux` would be a directory in the root of the file system and not the current directory. `./aux` or `aux` is what you mean, I take it.

Comment: This is related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433531/vim-latex-how-to-set-directory-for-latex-output-files/494282#494282) (I put an practical example with the option `build_dir` as suggested by @pierre below)

Answer (score 2):

You can mostly achieve this using **vimtex**'s `build_dir` setting (see **vimtex** help `:h vimtex_compiler_latexmk` and [this conversation](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/880) explaining that *"this allows to define an output directory where all generated files are put when compiling"*.). However, your pdf will also be moved to this directory.

Comment: Yeah the pdf going to that directory is not ideal. The ideal would be to separate the auxiliary files from the desired, generated pdf file.

Comment: @RACKGNOME If you run the `:h` command you'll see an option for a callback. Just use that to move the pdf back out of the build dir.