# vim-latex: How to set directory for latex output files

Tags: ubuntu, vim-latex

I am using version 1.8.23 of vim-latex suite in Ubuntu. I am able to compile and view latex files using vim through `\ll` and `\lv` commands. The compilation and viewing commands create `.dvi`, `.aux` and `.log` files in directory containing the file that is being compiled. I am looking for a way for these files to be created in an alternate directory such as `/tmp`.

I have looked at
http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/ and cound not find a way to do this.

Comment: Do you only want aux file in tmp or is it ok for the output file to go also to this directory?

Answer (score 7):

For users of [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), and not vim-latex, you can use the following option in your `.vimrc`

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
            \ 'out_dir' : 'build',
            \}
```

[Link to the documentation](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/doc/vimtex.txt#L848)

For those who try to keep the PDF or the DVI file out of this folder, this is only supported if you use MiKTex, and especially not with TexLive. [More info](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/220)

If you need a comparison between vimtex and vim-latex (aka Tex Suite), this is quite well explained on the [Readme page of vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex#alternativeshttps://github.com/lervag/vimtex#alternatives).

Answer (score 1):

Able to get all output files moved over to /tmp in latex suite with these lines added to .vimrc

```
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat="pdf"
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf='pdflatex --output-directory=/tmp -aux-directory=/tmp -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf='cd /tmp; AcroRd32'
```